# What is the proper implementation of all the thread context structs?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

Sorry for posting this but, I am struggling with implementing `GetThreadContext`and `SetThreadContext` because the structs are wrong, also they cause the library to throw a `ReflectionTypeLoadException`.

Here is my implementation of the structs:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct THREAD_CONTEXT_IA32
{
    public THREAD_CONTEXT_IA32(IA32_CONTEXT_FLAG flags) : this()
    {
        cFlags = flags;
    }

    private IA32_CONTEXT_FLAG cFlags;
    public int dr0;
    public int dr1;
    public int dr2;
    public int dr3;
    public int dr6;
    public int dr7;
    public FLOATING_SAVE_AREA floatSave;
    public int segGs;
    public int segFs;
    public int segEs;
    public int segDs;
    public int edi;
    public int esi;
    public int ebx;
    public int edx;
    public int ecx;
    public int eax;
    public int ebp;
    public int eip;
    public int segCs;
    public int eFlags;
    public int esp;
    public int segSs;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXIMUM_SUPPORTED_EXTENSION)]
    public byte[] extendedRegisters;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 16)]
public struct THREAD_CONTEXT_AMD64
{
    public THREAD_CONTEXT_AMD64(AMD64_CONTEXT_FLAG flags) : this()
    {
        cFlags = flags;
    }

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public long p1Home;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public long p2Home;
    [FieldOffset(16)]
    public long p3Home;
    [FieldOffset(24)]
    public long p4Home;
    [FieldOffset(32)]
    public long p5Home;
    [FieldOffset(40)]
    public long p6Home;
    [FieldOffset(48)]
    private AMD64_CONTEXT_FLAG cFlags;
    [FieldOffset(50)]
    public int mxCsr;
    [FieldOffset(54)]
    public short segCs;
    [FieldOffset(56)]
    public short segDs;
    [FieldOffset(58)]
    public short segEs;
    [FieldOffset(60)]
    public short segFs;
    [FieldOffset(62)]
    public short segGs;
    [FieldOffset(64)]
    public short segSs;
    [FieldOffset(66)]
    public int eFlags;
    [FieldOffset(70)]
    public long dr0;
    [FieldOffset(78)]
    public long dr1;
    [FieldOffset(86)]
    public long dr2;
    [FieldOffset(94)]
    public long dr3;
    [FieldOffset(102)]
    public long dr6;
    [FieldOffset(110)]
    public long dr7;
    [FieldOffset(118)]
    public long rax;
    [FieldOffset(126)]
    public long rcx;
    [FieldOffset(132)]
    public long rdx;
    [FieldOffset(140)]
    public long rbx;
    [FieldOffset(148)]
    public long rsp;
    [FieldOffset(156)]
    public long rbp;
    [FieldOffset(174)]
    public long rsi;
    [FieldOffset(182)]
    public long rdi;
    [FieldOffset(190)]
    public long r8;
    [FieldOffset(198)]
    public long r9;
    [FieldOffset(206)]
    public long r10;
    [FieldOffset(214)]
    public long r11;
    [FieldOffset(222)]
    public long r12;
    [FieldOffset(230)]
    public long r13;
    [FieldOffset(238)]
    public long r14;
    [FieldOffset(246)]
    public long r15;
    [FieldOffset(252)]
    public long rip;
    [FieldOffset(260)]
    public XSAVE_FORMAT fltSave;
    [FieldOffset(772)]
    public M128A header0;
    [FieldOffset(788)]
    public M128A header1;
    [FieldOffset(804)]
    public M128A legacy0;
    [FieldOffset(820)]
    public M128A legacy1;
    [FieldOffset(836)]
    public M128A legacy2;
    [FieldOffset(852)]
    public M128A legacy3;
    [FieldOffset(868)]
    public M128A legacy4;
    [FieldOffset(884)]
    public M128A legacy5;
    [FieldOffset(900)]
    public M128A legacy6;
    [FieldOffset(916)]
    public M128A legacy7;
    [FieldOffset(932)]
    public M128A xmm0;
    [FieldOffset(948)]
    public M128A xmm1;
    [FieldOffset(964)]
    public M128A xmm2;
    [FieldOffset(980)]
    public M128A xmm3;
    [FieldOffset(996)]
    public M128A xmm4;
    [FieldOffset(1012)]
    public M128A xmm5;
    [FieldOffset(1028)]
    public M128A xmm6;
    [FieldOffset(1044)]
    public M128A xmm7;
    [FieldOffset(1060)]
    public M128A xmm8;
    [FieldOffset(1076)]
    public M128A xmm9;
    [FieldOffset(1092)]
    public M128A xmm10;
    [FieldOffset(1108)]
    public M128A xmm11;
    [FieldOffset(1124)]
    public M128A xmm12;
    [FieldOffset(1140)]
    public M128A xmm13;
    [FieldOffset(1156)]
    public M128A xmm14;
    [FieldOffset(1172)]
    public M128A xmm15;
    [FieldOffset(1188)]
    public M128A vectorRegister0;
    [FieldOffset(1204)]
    public M128A vectorRegister1;
    [FieldOffset(1220)]
    public M128A vectorRegister2;
    [FieldOffset(1236)]
    public M128A vectorRegister3;
    [FieldOffset(1252)]
    public M128A vectorRegister4;
    [FieldOffset(1268)]
    public M128A vectorRegister5;
    [FieldOffset(1284)]
    public M128A vectorRegister6;
    [FieldOffset(1300)]
    public M128A vectorRegister7;
    [FieldOffset(1316)]
    public M128A vectorRegister8;
    [FieldOffset(1332)]
    public M128A vectorRegister9;
    [FieldOffset(1348)]
    public M128A vectorRegister10;
    [FieldOffset(1364)]
    public M128A vectorRegister11;
    [FieldOffset(1380)]
    public M128A vectorRegister12;
    [FieldOffset(1396)]
    public M128A vectorRegister13;
    [FieldOffset(1412)]
    public M128A vectorRegister14;
    [FieldOffset(1428)]
    public M128A vectorRegister15;
    [FieldOffset(1444)]
    public M128A vectorRegister16;
    [FieldOffset(1460)]
    public M128A vectorRegister17;
    [FieldOffset(1476)]
    public M128A vectorRegister18;
    [FieldOffset(1492)]
    public M128A vectorRegister19;
    [FieldOffset(1508)]
    public M128A vectorRegister20;
    [FieldOffset(1524)]
    public M128A vectorRegister21;
    [FieldOffset(1540)]
    public M128A vectorRegister22;
    [FieldOffset(1556)]
    public M128A vectorRegister23;
    [FieldOffset(1572)]
    public M128A vectorRegister24;
    [FieldOffset(1588)]
    public M128A vectorRegister25;
    [FieldOffset(1604)]
    public long vectorControl;
    [FieldOffset(1612)]
    public long debugControl;
    [FieldOffset(1620)]
    public long lastBranchToRip;
    [FieldOffset(1628)]
    public long lastBranchFromRip;
    [FieldOffset(1636)]
    public long lastExceptionToRip;
    [FieldOffset(1644)]
    public long lastExceptionFromRip;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 8)]
public struct THREAD_CONTEXT_ARM
{
    public THREAD_CONTEXT_ARM(ARM_CONTEXT_FLAG flags) : this()
    {
        cFlags = flags;
    }

    private ARM_CONTEXT_FLAG cFlags;
    public int r0;
    public int r1;
    public int r2;
    public int r3;
    public int r4;
    public int r5;
    public int r6;
    public int r7;
    public int r8;
    public int r9;
    public int r10;
    public int r11;
    public int r12;
    public int sp;
    public int lr;
    public int pc;
    public int cpsr;
    public int fpscr;
    public int padding;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
    public NEON128[] neon;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = ARM_MAX_BREAKPOINTS)]
    public int[] bvr;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = ARM_MAX_BREAKPOINTS)]
    public int[] bcr;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = ARM_MAX_WATCHPOINTS)]
    public int[] wvr;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = ARM_MAX_WATCHPOINTS)]
    public int[] wcr;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
    public int[] padding2;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 16)]
public struct THREAD_CONTEXT_ARM64
{
    public THREAD_CONTEXT_ARM64(ARM64_CONTEXT_FLAG flags) : this()
    {
        cFlags = flags;
    }

    private ARM64_CONTEXT_FLAG cFlags;
    public int cpsr;
    public long x0;
    public long x1;
    public long x2;
    public long x3;
    public long x4;
    public long x5;
    public long x6;
    public long x7;
    public long x8;
    public long x9;
    public long x10;
    public long x11;
    public long x12;
    public long x13;
    public long x14;
    public long x15;
    public long x16;
    public long x17;
    public long x18;
    public long x19;
    public long x20;
    public long x21;
    public long x22;
    public long x23;
    public long x24;
    public long x25;
    public long x26;
    public long x27;
    public long x28;
    public long fp;
    public long lr;
    public long sp;
    public long pc;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
    public NEON128[] neon;
    public int fpcr;
    public int fpsr;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = ARM64_MAX_BREAKPOINTS)]
    public int[] bcr;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = ARM64_MAX_BREAKPOINTS)]
    public long[] bvr;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = ARM64_MAX_WATCHPOINTS)]
    public int[] wcr;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = ARM64_MAX_WATCHPOINTS)]
    public long[] wvr;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct THREAD_CONTEXT_WOW64
{
    public THREAD_CONTEXT_WOW64(WOW64_CONTEXT_FLAG flags) : this()
    {
        cFlags = flags;
    }

    private WOW64_CONTEXT_FLAG cFlags;
    public int dr0;
    public int dr1;
    public int dr2;
    public int dr3;
    public int dr6;
    public int dr7;
    public FLOATING_SAVE_AREA floatSave;
    public int segGs;
    public int segFs;
    public int segEs;
    public int segDs;
    public int edi;
    public int esi;
    public int ebx;
    public int edx;
    public int ecx;
    public int eax;
    public int ebp;
    public int eip;
    public int segCs;
    public int eFlags;
    public int esp;
    public int segSs;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXIMUM_SUPPORTED_EXTENSION)]
    public byte[] extendedRegisters;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct FLOATING_SAVE_AREA
{
    public int controlWord;
    public int statusWord;
    public int tagWord;
    public int errorOffset;
    public int errorSelector;
    public int dataOffset;
    public int dataSelector;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = SIZE_OF_80387_REGISTERS)]
    public byte[] registerArea;
    public int spare0;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 16)]
public struct M128A
{
    public M128A(ulong _low, long _high)
    {
        low = _low;

        high = _high;
    }

    public ulong low;
    public long high;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct NEON128
{
    public NEON128(ulong _low, long _high)
    {
        low = _low;

        high = _high;
    }

    public ulong low;
    public long high;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 16)]
public struct XSAVE_FORMAT
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public short controlWord;
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public short statusWord;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public byte tagWord;
    [FieldOffset(5)]
    private byte reserved0;
    [FieldOffset(6)]
    public short errorOpcode;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public int errorOffset;
    [FieldOffset(12)]
    public short errorSelector;
    [FieldOffset(14)]
    private ushort reserved1;
    [FieldOffset(16)]
    public int dataOffset;
    [FieldOffset(20)]
    public short dataSelector;
    [FieldOffset(22)]
    private ushort reserved2;
    [FieldOffset(24)]
    public int mxCsr;
    [FieldOffset(28)]
    public int mxCsrMask;
    [FieldOffset(32)]
    public M128A floatRegister0;
    [FieldOffset(48)]
    public M128A floatRegister1;
    [FieldOffset(64)]
    public M128A floatRegister2;
    [FieldOffset(80)]
    public M128A floatRegister3;
    [FieldOffset(96)]
    public M128A floatRegister4;
    [FieldOffset(112)]
    public M128A floatRegister5;
    [FieldOffset(128)]
    public M128A floatRegister6;
    [FieldOffset(144)]
    public M128A floatRegister7;
    [FieldOffset(160)]
    public M128A xmmRegister0;
    [FieldOffset(176)]
    public M128A xmmRegister1;
    [FieldOffset(192)]
    public M128A xmmRegister2;
    [FieldOffset(208)]
    public M128A xmmRegister3;
    [FieldOffset(224)]
    public M128A xmmRegister4;
    [FieldOffset(240)]
    public M128A xmmRegister5;
    [FieldOffset(256)]
    public M128A xmmRegister6;
    [FieldOffset(272)]
    public M128A xmmRegister7;
    [FieldOffset(288)]
    public M128A xmmRegister8;
    [FieldOffset(304)]
    public M128A xmmRegister9;
    [FieldOffset(320)]
    public M128A xmmRegister10;
    [FieldOffset(336)]
    public M128A xmmRegister11;
    [FieldOffset(352)]
    public M128A xmmRegister12;
    [FieldOffset(368)]
    public M128A xmmRegister13;
    [FieldOffset(384)]
    public M128A xmmRegister14;
    [FieldOffset(400)]
    public M128A xmmRegister15;
    [FieldOffset(416)]
    private M128A Reserved3_0;
    [FieldOffset(432)]
    private M128A Reserved3_1;
    [FieldOffset(448)]
    private M128A Reserved3_2;
    [FieldOffset(464)]
    private M128A Reserved3_3;
    [FieldOffset(480)]
    private M128A Reserved3_4;
    [FieldOffset(496)]
    private M128A Reserved3_5;
}
```

Any help with this would be appreciated. Note that all flag enums are uint. Am pretty sure one or more offsets are wrong but not sure where (have looked over them 5 times already)

Comment: Have you compared it with this https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.GetThreadContext

Comment: What you can do is compile these structure with C++, and use sizeof, offsetof, etc. in various architecture, to double check your values.

Comment: M128A differs in order from the link @TheGeneral posted

Comment: Perhaps the exception has something to do with the imported function signatures. Could you post those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me (tested in x86 and x64 on Windows 10 64) =>

```
// Check sizes
// 716
int nSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CONTEXT));
// 1232
int nSize64 = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CONTEXT64));

CONTEXT ctx = new CONTEXT();
// CONTEXT64 ctx = new CONTEXT64();

ctx.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_ALL;                
bool bRet = GetThreadContext(GetCurrentThread(), ref ctx);
```

with (from SDK headers and *WinDbg*) :

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 16)]
    public struct CONTEXT64
    {
        [FieldOffset(0x000)]
        public ulong P1Home;
        [FieldOffset(0x008)]
        public ulong P2Home;
        [FieldOffset(0x010)]
        public ulong P3Home;
        [FieldOffset(0x018)]
        public ulong P4Home;
        [FieldOffset(0x020)]
        public ulong P5Home;
        [FieldOffset(0x028)]
        public ulong P6Home;
        [FieldOffset(0x030)]
        public int ContextFlags;
        [FieldOffset(0x034)]
        public int MxCsr;
        [FieldOffset(0x038)]
        public ushort SegCs;
        [FieldOffset(0x03a)]
        public ushort SegDs;
        [FieldOffset(0x03c)]
        public ushort SegEs;
        [FieldOffset(0x03e)]
        public ushort SegFs;
        [FieldOffset(0x040)]
        public ushort SegGs;
        [FieldOffset(0x042)]
        public ushort SegSs;
        [FieldOffset(0x044)]
        public int EFlags;

        [FieldOffset(0x048)]
        public ulong Dr0;
        [FieldOffset(0x050)]
        public ulong Dr1;
        [FieldOffset(0x058)]
        public ulong Dr2;
        [FieldOffset(0x060)]
        public ulong Dr3;
        [FieldOffset(0x068)]
        public ulong Dr6;
        [FieldOffset(0x070)]
        public ulong Dr7;
        [FieldOffset(0x078)]
        public ulong Rax;
        [FieldOffset(0x080)]
        public ulong Rcx;
        [FieldOffset(0x088)]
        public ulong Rdx;
        [FieldOffset(0x090)]
        public ulong Rbx;
        [FieldOffset(0x098)]
        public ulong Rsp;
        [FieldOffset(0x0a0)]
        public ulong Rbp;
        [FieldOffset(0x0a8)]
        public ulong Rsi;
        [FieldOffset(0x0b0)]
        public ulong Rdi;

        [FieldOffset(0x0b8)]
        public ulong R8;
        [FieldOffset(0x0c0)]
        public ulong R9;
        [FieldOffset(0x0c8)]
        public ulong R10;
        [FieldOffset(0x0d0)]
        public ulong R11;
        [FieldOffset(0x0d8)]
        public ulong R12;
        [FieldOffset(0x0e0)]
        public ulong R13;
        [FieldOffset(0x0e8)]
        public ulong R14;
        [FieldOffset(0x0f0)]
        public ulong R15;
        [FieldOffset(0x0f8)]
        public ulong Rip;

        [FieldOffset(0x100)]
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 512)]
        public XMM_SAVE_AREA32 FltSave;

        [FieldOffset(0x300)]
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 26)]
        public M128A[] VectorRegister;
        [FieldOffset(0x4a0)]
        public ulong VectorControl;
        [FieldOffset(0x4a8)]
        public ulong DebugControl;
        [FieldOffset(0x4b0)]
        public ulong LastBranchToRip;
        [FieldOffset(0x4b8)]
        public ulong LastBranchFromRip;
        [FieldOffset(0x4c0)]
        public ulong LastExceptionToRip;
        [FieldOffset(0x4c8)]
        public ulong LastExceptionFromRip;
    }


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 16)]
    public struct XMM_SAVE_AREA32
    {
        public ushort ControlWord;
        public ushort StatusWord;
        public char TagWord;
        public char Reserved1;
        public ushort ErrorOpcode;
        public uint ErrorOffset;
        public ushort ErrorSelector;
        public ushort Reserved2;
        public uint DataOffset;
        public ushort DataSelector;
        public ushort Reserved3;
        public uint MxCsr;
        public uint MxCsrMask;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        public M128A[] FloatRegisters;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
        public M128A[] XmmRegisters;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 96)]
        public char[] Reserved4;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct FLOATING_SAVE_AREA
    {
        public int ControlWord;
        public int StatusWord;
        public int TagWord;
        public int ErrorOffset;
        public int ErrorSelector;
        public int DataOffset;
        public int DataSelector;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = SIZE_OF_80387_REGISTERS)]
        public byte[] RegisterArea;
        public int Spare0;
    }

    public const int MAXIMUM_SUPPORTED_EXTENSION = 512;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
    public struct CONTEXT
    {
        public int ContextFlags;

        public int Dr0;
        public int Dr1;
        public int Dr2;
        public int Dr3;
        public int Dr6;
        public int Dr7;

        public FLOATING_SAVE_AREA FloatSave;

        public int SegGs;
        public int SegFs;
        public int SegEs;
        public int SegDs;

        public int Edi;
        public int Esi;
        public int Ebx;
        public int Edx;
        public int Ecx;
        public int Eax;

        public int Ebp;
        public int Eip;
        public int SegCs;              // MUST BE SANITIZED
        public int EFlags;             // MUST BE SANITIZED
        public int Esp;
        public int SegSs;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXIMUM_SUPPORTED_EXTENSION)]
        public byte[] ExtendedRegisters;
    }

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetCurrentThread();

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern bool GetThreadContext(IntPtr hThread, ref CONTEXT lpContext);

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern bool GetThreadContext(IntPtr hThread, ref CONTEXT64 lpContext);

    public const int SIZE_OF_80387_REGISTERS = 80;

    public const int CONTEXT_i386 = 0x00010000;    // this assumes that i386 and
    public const int CONTEXT_i486 = 0x00010000;    // i486 have identical context records

    public const int CONTEXT_CONTROL = (CONTEXT_i386 | 0x00000001); // SS:SP, CS:IP, FLAGS, BP
    public const int CONTEXT_INTEGER = (CONTEXT_i386 | 0x00000002); // AX, BX, CX, DX, SI, DI
    public const int CONTEXT_SEGMENTS = (CONTEXT_i386 | 0x00000004); // DS, ES, FS, GS
    public const int CONTEXT_FLOATING_POINT = (CONTEXT_i386 | 0x00000008); // 387 state
    public const int CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS = (CONTEXT_i386 | 0x00000010); // DB 0-3,6,7
    public const int CONTEXT_EXTENDED_REGISTERS = (CONTEXT_i386 | 0x00000020); // cpu specific extensions

    public const int CONTEXT_FULL = (CONTEXT_CONTROL | CONTEXT_INTEGER | CONTEXT_SEGMENTS);

    public const int CONTEXT_ALL = (CONTEXT_CONTROL | CONTEXT_INTEGER | CONTEXT_SEGMENTS | CONTEXT_FLOATING_POINT | CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS | CONTEXT_EXTENDED_REGISTERS);
    public const int CONTEXT_XSTATE = (CONTEXT_i386 | 0x00000040);

    public const int CONTEXT_EXCEPTION_ACTIVE = 0x08000000;
    public const int CONTEXT_SERVICE_ACTIVE = 0x10000000;
    public const int CONTEXT_EXCEPTION_REQUEST = 0x40000000;
    public const int CONTEXT_EXCEPTION_REPORTING = unchecked((int)0x80000000);
```